# Using Laravel Auth and Sentry together

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I am developing an application in laravel. This application has two kind of user and these types have different properties. So I want them to be seperate from each other. 
Can I use Sentry and Laravel Auth together. Each system must have its own tables. Can they work at the same time. Is it possible that they have an conflict between them. For example in cookies or whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

Managing more than one type of users is not a reason for using two autheintication systems. If you have many user types, you can create a 'User' table and another table for each user type, related to the user table.

Authenticate the User with Auth **or** Sentry, and then get its properties from the table you need depending on the user type.

Comment: But I want the user systems to be able to have same usernames at the same times. It is a possible stuation in my case.